# Creating PDF file through ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, pdf

What is required to create a PDF file through an ASP.NET application other than Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iText#, it's based on a similar Java project.

http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/

You don't need Crystal Reports in conjunction with this. If you need something more robust (but pricey), I have used this to great success with complex PDFs:

http://www.pdflib.com/

Answer (score 0):

One possible library is [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/).  Apparently iText is a huge deal, but I didn't really see it when working with iTextSharp on a requirement, but that was years ago.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is use a third party library.  I've used ASPOSE.PDF in the past with good results.

http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net-and-java/default.aspx

I also tried PDF Sharp, its open source, but wasn't as flexable.

http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/

Answer (score 0):

You have several open source options [here](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries).

Answer (score -2):

```
protected void btnReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    showReport();

}

private void showReport()

{

    DataTable dat = Reports.getPartyWiseJobStatusReport(Convert.ToInt16(ddlDivName.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt16(ddlJobGroup.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt16(ddlProjectStatus.SelectedValue));

    ReportDocument rptdoc = new ReportDocument();

    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/rptPartyWiseJobStatus.rpt");

    rptdoc.Load(path);

    rptdoc.SetDataSource(dat);

    //rptdoc.SetParameterValue(0, ddlDivName.SelectedItem.Text);
    //ExportOptions exportOpts1 = rptdoc.ExportOptions;
    rptdoc.ExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;

    rptdoc.ExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;

    rptdoc.ExportOptions.DestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();

    ((DiskFileDestinationOptions)rptdoc.ExportOptions.DestinationOptions).DiskFileName = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/rptPartyWiseJobStatus.pdf");

    rptdoc.Export();

    rptdoc.Close();

    rptdoc.Dispose();

    Response.ClearContent();

    Response.ClearHeaders();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=rptPartyWiseJobStatus.pdf");

    Response.WriteFile("~/Reports/rptPartyWiseJobStatus.pdf");

    Response.Flush();

    Response.Close();

    File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/rptPartyWiseJobStatus.pdf"));

}
```

public static DataTable getPartyWiseJobStatusReport(Int16 DivisionID, Int16 JobGroup, Int16 ProjectStatus)

{
        string _procName = "sp_T_Proposal_SelectPartyWiseJobStatus";

```
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

    Database objDatabase = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

    DbCommand objDbCommand = objDatabase.GetStoredProcCommand(_procName);

    objDatabase.AddInParameter(objDbCommand, "@DivisionID", DbType.Int16, DivisionID);

    objDatabase.AddInParameter(objDbCommand, "@JobGroup", DbType.Int16, JobGroup);

    objDatabase.AddInParameter(objDbCommand, "@ProjectStatus", DbType.Int16, ProjectStatus);

    using (IDataReader dr = objDatabase.ExecuteReader(objDbCommand))

    {

        dt1.Load(dr);

    }

    return dt1;

}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are difficult to understand, when someone is trying to actually figure something out, rather than just "show me teh codez'.